# any way to get javascript variable memory address?

Tags: javascript

is there any way to get the **memory address** of the JavaScript variable , cause when comparing things like `[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` which is looks like `true` but it is `false` , and also this memory address will help me to understand mutable and immutability of strings too

Comment: no, and you never need to .. .`looks like true` only to the uninitiated :p

Comment: Removed all those tags that are irrelevant. (Im)mutability is not explained by memory addresses. Strings are *always* immutable in JavaScript.

Comment: comparing arrays where all the values are primitives (with the exception of Symbol) can be done... `[1, false, 4n, "hello"].toString() === [1, false, 4n, "hello"].toString()`

Comment: Well your browser's dev tools can give it to you, if you've got time to dig in all the objects that are allocated in order to find *yours*. But anyway that'd be misleading for js.

Comment: @trincot - aren't all the other primitives immutable too? (Number, Boolean, BigInt, Symbol)

Comment: @tricot thanks for removing , actually i am new so newbie mistakes , previously i learnt python in that mutabality and immubability are much understandable with the help of showing memory address of variable of what we are comparing

Comment: @lucky, but object variables that have the same address can reference a mutable object or not, and object variables that have a different address can reference a mutable object or not. It doesn't relate. It doesn't help to know an object's address to say anything about immutability.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript itself is meant to be implementation-agnostic, so concepts like memory addresses are intentionally absent from the language itself. Outside of the language, you can use the browser's debugging tools to take a memory snapshot, and that might contain the information. Note, however, that there is no real guarantee that an object will retain its address.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).